# Device Administrator Password Lock Screen issue in Android

Tags: android

I am working on security Related application in android. I am using DeviceAdminReceiver  to lock the device,set password and to wipe data.Everything working fine.But My problem is wen i lock device using admin other user(other than device owner)can Guess and enter any random passwords device may get Activated. If this is the case my Application not Effective.I am also using **Maximum failed password attempts** to wipe after few wrong attempts, I want to hide **Enter password to unlock** screen in some special situation.My Question is

1. `When Device Locked by DeviceAdminReceiver, How i can prevent unauthorized user to enter password?`

reference: [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/training/device-management-policy/index.html) sample code. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can completely hide this unlock screen. I would suggest setting a very hard to guess password (very long, mix letters/numbers etc).

I also used an android application at one point ([Lost Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gadgetprojects.lostphone&hl=en)) that put a screen overtop of the current screen (whatever it was) and whenever you tried to close it it reopened, effectively preventing anyone from using the phone until they wiped it, or entered the correct password. That approach is somewhat more 'hacky', and doesn't stop someone from uninstalling the application using adb.